# Convert timestamps without adding yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

I want to convert timestamps from characters to time but I do not want any date. On top of that, it must display milliseconds, as in "hh:mm:ss,os".

If I use `as.POSIXCT` it always adds a date prefix to my timestamp and that is not my intention. I also checked the `lubridate` package but I can't seem to find a function that goes beyond "as.hms" so that it displays at least two digits in milliseconds.

Example using POSIXct

```
df <-c("01:31:12.20","01:31:14.56","01:31:14.84")

options(digits.secs = 2)
df <- as.POSIXct(df, format="%H:%M:%OS")
```

This is the outcome:

```
[1] "2019-03-15 01:31:12.20 EDT" "2019-03-15 01:31:14.55 EDT"
[3] "2019-03-15 01:31:14.83 EDT"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because the chron() function format is also "hh:mm:ss", it doesn't have milliseconds.

Comment: date time needs date as well if I understand

Comment: True. I'll edit the "date" bit out.

Comment: ok, then it is not clear what you really wanted because `hms(df)` converts it to `Period` class

Comment: I just want my timestamps that are in char format to be converted to a time format so I can perform calculation with them.

I would like to have them formatted into a "hourhour:minuteminute:secondsecond.millisecondmillisecond" format.

Comment: ok, then what is the issue with `POSIXct` conversion or `hms(df)` where you can get all the components extracted

Comment: It displays the date as a prefix as seen on the original post.

PS: That date is just today's date, as it is what `POSIXct` does by default.

Comment: ok, so it is a print issue.  You could create your own method print to display only that the time part

Comment: Right. I'm kind of new at this. How would you do it? Thank you

Comment: Have you considered to first perform all of your calculations in the format that it is in and in the end to finally convert to "H:M:S" as text? The code `strftime(df, format="%H:%M:%S")` will convert your df into a characters in the desired time format.

Comment: Fortunately the calculations work as intended. I'm just surprised it's hard to find a function that would maintain the original integrity of the data.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @goncaloveiga You need the date to perform calculations on time. Then you can reformat your data using `format`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the `hms` package does what the OP expects. `hms` *implements an S3 class for storing and formatting time-of-day values, based on the 'difftime' class.*

```
library(hms)
as.hms(df)
```

> ```
> 01:31:12.200000
> 01:31:14.560000
> 01:31:14.840000
> ```

It can be used for calculation, e.g.,

```
diff(as.hms(df))
```

> ```
> 00:00:02.360000
> 00:00:00.280000
> ```

Please, note that the `print()` and `format()` methods do not accept other parameters and do not respect `options(digits.secs = 2)`.

---

The `hms` class is similar to `lubridate`'s `as.hms()` function which creates a period object:

```
lubridate::hms(df)
```

> ```
> [1] "1H 31M 12.2S"  "1H 31M 14.56S" "1H 31M 14.84S"
> ```

Arithmetic can be done as well:

```
diff(lubridate::hms(df))
```

> ```
> [1] 2.36 0.28
> ```

Please, be aware that the internal representation of time, date, and datetime objects usually is based on numeric types to allow for doing calculations. The internal representation is different from the character string when the object is printed.

---

The `ITime` class in the `data.table` package is a time-of-day class which stores the integer number of seconds in the day. So, it cannot handle milliseconds.